# Does this grouping of matrix elements have a specific name?

Tags: matrices, terminology

I am doing some research into social interactions and the data is represented in a series of square matrices for analysis.

I am interested if the grouping of matrix elements above/below off-diagonal, as highlighted by blue and green in the following diagram, are known by a specific name? These groupings of matrix elements differs from the upper/lower triangular matrix as they don't include the main diagonal and all the elements can be greater than zero. I have searched for a name but have not found anything yet.

[image]

Also does the sum of these groupings have a specific name? (Akin to the sum of the main diagonal being called the trace).

If there are no conventional names, I am okay to defining a name for each grouping and their respective sums as part of the research.

Comment: I call them strict upper/lower triangle.

Comment: Green part = *strictly* lower triangular part of $A$. Blue part = strictly upper triangular part of $A$. Green + blue = off-diagonal part of $A$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson - doesn't the "strict upper/lower triangle" require some of elements of the matrix to be zero (see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrictlyUpperTriangularMatrix.html)? My situation is the any of the matrix elements can be zero or greater.

Comment: @user1551 - see above comment